# ¿Pueden explicarme cómo funciona este código?

Tags: python

¿pueden explicarme cómo funciona este código por favor? No comprendo cómo llega al resultado final. Gracias por adelantado.

```
def numbers(n):
    if n>0:
        result = n + numbers(n-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
numbers(4)
output: 1
3
6
10
10
```

Comment: Googlea "recursividad". Googlea "cómo hacer una traza de un código", especialmente esta última cosa te será ***absolutamente necesaria*** en tu vida como programador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se llama recursividad, y nos dice que la componen 2 cosas: Un caso base para que este pueda ejecutarse y, una condición que decremente (o aumente) para salir del caso base. Trabajemos con una prueba de escritorio (te recomiendo aprenderlo, te ayudara a comprender los algoritmos de mejor manera)

Primera iteración, tendrás por defecto el cuatro, ese numero se va a guardar en la variable resultado. Solo se guarda, no se ejecuta. Ya que necesitas salir del caso base para que todo se ejecute. Iniciamos con 4:

```
if 4 > 0:
        result = 4 + numbers(4-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
```

Segunda iteración, aun se cumple el caso base, decrecimos en uno la variable n, quedando asi:

```
if 3 > 0:
        result = 3 + numbers(3-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
```

Tercera iteración, aun no salimos del caso base, por lo cual se debe seguir ejecutando el algoritmo:

```
if 2 > 0:
        result = 2 + numbers(2-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
```

cuarta iteración, lo mismo que la tercera iteración, aun no sales del caso base, por lo tanto se sigue ejecutando el algoritmo.

```
if 1>0:
        result = 1 + numbers(1-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
```

Por ultimo, la quinta iteración se ejecuta y, oh sorpresa, aquí se rompe todo. Nos damos cuenta que, 0 no es mayor a 0.

```
if 0 > 0:
        result = 0 + numbers(0-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
```

Ya podemos ejecutarlo:

- Comienzas con cero.
- Luego comienzas con el 1
- El cual vas a sumar con 2 = 3
- Ese 3 lo sumas con el siguiente numero, que te da 6
- Por ultimo, ese 6 lo sumas con el 4 = 10

```
4+(4-1) 
     3+(3-1) = 6
          2+(2-1) = 3
               1(1-1) = 1 
                   0
```

Algo mas entendible, seria de esta manera.

```
0,  1 + 2 = 3 
             3 + 3 = 6 
                     6 + 4 = 10;
```

Comment: Excelente manera de realizar una traza. Ojalá más gente supiese coger un lápiz y un papel y realizar una, la mitad de las preguntas de SO desaparecerían!